# javascript move to NextSibling div offset while counter ends

Tags: jquery, for-loop, jquery-animate, setinterval

this is what I have as example:
https://jsfiddle.net/nerdkal/txmonrkf/

My code can: 
   find next sibling, get next sibling (id,top,left) to animate, and it does. But what I can't do moves until "jumps" reach 0 jumps.

this is what I wanna move:

```
#box {
    top: 60px; left: 76px;width: 33px; height: 29px; position: absolute; background-color: yellow; z-index:1;
}
```

this is part what I have:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var jumps = 2;

    var start = document.getElementById("start").id;
    var prevhouse = document.getElementById(start).previousElementSibling.innerHTML; 
    var nexthouse = document.getElementById(start).nextElementSibling.innerHTML; 

    var nexthouseX = 121;
  document.getElementById(nexthouse).offsetTop;
    var nexthouseY = 40;
  document.getElementById(nexthouse).offsetLeft;

$("button").click(function(){
      $('#box').animate({left: nexthouseX +'px', top: nexthouseY +'px'},1500);
      start = document.getElementById(start).nextElementSibling.innerHTML;
      jumps--;
      $('#result').html("jumps: " + jumps + "<br>"+ start); 
      });
      $('#result').html("jumps: " + jumps +"<br>"+ start); 

});
```

The #results are just for notice me how many jumps remains and where I am(house).

What I need: find a way to my box give one more jump after 2 seconds (or many jumps I could set), i know that I will need a loop but i can't make by myself.

I would like some help, since now, I would like to say thanks just for u read it, maybe to many of u guys it can be easy but to me, it's freak hard. thks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will increment the number of jumps every 2 seconds, and stop the user from jumping if there are no jumps left.

```
$(function() {
  var jumps = 2;
  var nexthouse = $("#start");

  $("button").click(function() {

    if (jumps > 0) {
      nexthouse = $(nexthouse).next();
      var nx = nexthouse.offset().top + 16;
      var ny = nexthouse.offset().left + 8;
      $('#box').animate({
        left: ny + 'px',
        top: nx + 'px'
      }, 500);
      jumps--;
    }
  });

  setInterval(function() {
    jumps++;
  }, 2000);
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ArcaneCraeda/txmonrkf/4/)

If you're not familiar with jquery, feel free to ask any questions, or take a look at the docs, particularly those for `$(function(){})`, `offset()`, `next()` and `setInterval(f(){})`. Oh, and mark as accepted if it's what you need.

Comment: ooh thnks, I think this helps a lot, I gonna read about NEXT() as u said to finish this function. You might saved the day, u rox! :D

Comment: Happy to help! If this answered your question, please mark it as solved, or do so when it is solved.